# How can i change the color of an error message in stripes framework

Tags: java, jsp, stripes

I am trying to change the color of error message. I am using a Stripes validation.If the validation failed, I am sending a error message. I wanted it in red color.But it shows in black color. How can i change the color of error message in Stripes framework.

Following is what i have tried.

```
        <div class="item">

            <stripes:errors />
            <stripes:form name="home"action="/home.action">
                //contents
              </stripes:form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Go through this [PDF](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/fdstr/errormessages.pdf). Might be useful.

Comment: it's the ui that decides how an error message is shown, not the validation

Answer (score 1):

As Vinoth says you can apply CSS classes to change the appearance of error messages. In addition to that, Stripes messages can be fully customized by editing `StripesResources.properties`.

Here you can define exactly what your messages will look like, using markup and CSS classes, or even inline styles.

```
# Resource strings used by the <stripes:errors> tag when there are no nested tags
stripes.errors.header=<div class="my-error-wrapper"><h4>Ooops... some things went awfully awry:/h4><ol>
stripes.errors.beforeError=<li><i class="fa fa-warning"></i>&nbsp;
stripes.errors.afterError=</li>
stripes.errors.footer=</ol></div>

# Resource strings used by the <stripes:errors> tag when displaying errors for a
# specific field (e.g. <stripes:errors field="password"/>). If not supplied the
# values above will be used instead.
stripes.fieldErrors.header=
stripes.fieldErrors.beforeError=<span class="my-error-inline"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i>&nbsp;
stripes.fieldErrors.afterError=</span>
stripes.fieldErrors.footer=

# Resource strings used by the stripes:messages tag
stripes.messages.header=<div class="my-message-wrapper"><ul>
stripes.messages.beforeMessage=<li>
stripes.messages.afterMessage=</li>
stripes.messages.footer=</ul></div>
```

As you can see you can add extra fancy stuff like [FontAwesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons (admitted, this goes a little further than OP asks for).

Answer (score 0):

Using selectors to specify error classes. This apply a global error style to input fields,

```
input.error, textarea.error {
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
}

input.error[type="radio"], input.error[type="checkbox"], select.error {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Read the [**Stripes Manual**](https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Display+Errors) for more information.